# django-rest-framework deserialize request to create a object with user foreign key

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'd like to create a `SpiderService` with a foreign key `request.user`.

models:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SpiderService(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

serializers:

```
class SpiderServiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        model = SpiderService
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'name') 

class SpiderServiceListSerializer(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SpiderService.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SpiderService
```

views:

```
class SpiderServiceList(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        services = SpiderService.objects.all()
        serializer = SpiderServiceSerializer(services, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SpiderServiceSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def perform_create(elf, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

when I post

```
{
    "name": "2"
}
```

to the api url, got 500 error:

```
[01/Feb/2016 15:39:55] "POST /services/ HTTP/1.1" 500 17105
IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: spmanage_spiderservice.user_id
```

I have read [Serializer relations](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/) and found I should not write code as above. The official example is equal to remove `user field` in `SpiderServiceSerializer`, and add a `spiderservice field` to a `UserSerializer`.Seems aim to achieve the syntax like `user.spiderservice_set` in django models, which do not fit my purpose.

I just want to create a spiderservice object with `request.user`.

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the current user as an [extra parameter to the Serializer's save method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#passing-additional-attributes-to-save):

```
serializer.save(user=request.user)
```

Comment: You are right, thanks!  But is there another way to auto fill user field?  It say `"user"` is required after  I remove `user = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.id')`.

Comment: I don't get your comment

Comment: You say my user field is `read_only`, so I remove it.Then validation error occurs , which says "user" is required. Does it mean I have to save a foreign key by myself?

Comment: I never said or implied that you remove the `read_only` argument

Comment: I know  keep the user field and add `serializer.save(user=request.user)` would work.I treat what your says `As your field is...`  as `Because your field is...` at first sight, this setence also have the meaning about `because I define the field ,so I have to save request.user myself`, but remove `user field` do not work in fact.So I just want to know if there is a way to save `request.user` automatically.

Comment: Right, I removed the mention to the `read_only` argument. Passing the user argument to `serializer.save` should do whether or not you have that field defined.

Answer (score 0):

do you have any Account serializer for the user model ??
if so, in your SpiderServiceSerializer try this :

```
user = AccountSerializer(read_only=True, required=False)
```